# How do I factor out nested for loops?

Tags: c++

Often times, I need to do bulk operations on a set of class data. Consider these classes:

```cpp
#include <vector>


class Component {
public:
    bool isFixed;
    int a, b, c;

    Component():
    isFixed(false),
    a(0), b(0), c(0)
    {}
};


class System {
public:
    std::vector<Component> components;

    System(int numComponents):
    components(numComponents)
    {}
};


class Universe {
public:
    std::vector<System> systems;

    Universe(int numSystems, int numComponents):
    systems(numSystems, System(numComponents))
    {}
};
```

Now, doing a single operation to every `Component` in a `Universe` becomes a matter of looping through all the `Component`s of all the `System`s in a `Universe`: a nested `for` loop.

```cpp
// Fixes a Component.
//
void fixComponent(Component& c) {c.isFixed = true;}


// Adds a number to the pieces of a Component.
//
void addToComponent(Component& cmp, double k)
{
    cmp.a += k;
    cmp.b += k;
    cmp.c += k;
}


// Fixes all components in a Universe.
//
void fixAllComponents(Universe& universe)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < universe.systems.size(); ++i) {

        System& thisSystem = universe.systems.at(i);

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < thisSystem.components.size(); ++j) {
            fixComponent(thisSystem.components.at(j));
        }
    }
}


// Adds a number to all components in a Universe.
//
void addToAllComponents(Universe& universe, double k)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < universe.systems.size(); ++i) {

        System& thisSystem = universe.systems.at(i);

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < thisSystem.components.size(); ++j) {
            addToComponent(thisSystem.components.at(j), k);
        }
    }
}
```

Writing the iterative `for` loops twice is OK, but I could easily have 20 different task to perform on this data, having to rewrite the double `for` every time. Needless to say, this can be error-prone. It would be nice if I could somehow reuse the iterating code and just focus on the distinct individual tasks.

**Question**
Is there a standard way to "factor out" the `for` loops when iterating over a set?

**Attempt**
After some thinking, I decided to write a function that takes 2 parameters, the object containing the data to iterate over and a pointer to a function that performs the task.

```cpp
void forEachComponent(Universe& u, void (*task)(Component&))
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < u.systems.size(); ++i) {

        System& thisSystem = u.systems.at(i);

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < thisSystem.components.size(); ++j) {
            task(thisSystem.components.at(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to fix a component, I can simply call `forEachComponent()` and pass in the task to be performed.

```cpp
Universe theUniverse(20, 30);
forEachComponent(theUniverse, fixComponent);
```

The obvious problem with this "solution" is that for every task that involves different parameters like `addToComponent()`, I have to write another function that takes a pointer to a function with those parameters, which defeats the purpose of factoring out the `for` loops.

Comment: Your `task` gets a reference to the Component. The task(s) can do whatever it needs. So I'm not sure why you think the signature of the task is changing or needs to change.

Comment: @lakeweb You are right so long as the task does not require information outside of the ```Component``` itself. For example ```addToComponent()``` takes a ref to the ```Component``` and a ```double```, therefore ```task(Component&)``` becomes ```task(Component&, double)```.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, you are using different signatures. As answered, functors are the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reuse the logic for iterating over the components by using functors.

```
template <typename Functor >
void forEachComponent(Universe& universe, Functor functor)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < universe.systems.size(); ++i) {

        System& thisSystem = universe.systems.at(i);

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < thisSystem.components.size(); ++j) {
            functor(thisSystem.components.at(j));
        }
    }
}

// Fixes all components in a Universe.
void fixAllComponents(Universe& universe)
{
   forEachComponent(universe, [](Component& c) {fixComponent(c);});
}


// Adds a number to all components in a Universe.
void addToAllComponents(Universe& universe, double k)
{
   forEachComponent(universe, [k](Component& c) {addToComponent(c, k);});
}
```

You can simplify `forEachComponent` by using range-`for` loops.

```
template <typename Functor >
void forEachComponent(Universe& universe, Functor functor)
{
    for(System& system : universe.systems) {
        for(Component& c : system.components) {
            functor(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 100% this. Textbook case. Great solution.

Comment: Though I'd drop the `-> void` noise. Also you're missing a couple of `;`

Comment: I'd also _probably_ make it a member of `Universe` but that's subjective

Answer (score 3):

An OOP way to do this is define an abstract class:

```
class Task {
    void execute(Component &) = 0;
}
```

Now you can define `forEachComponent()` as

```
void forEachComponent(Universe& u, Task& task)
```

and call `task.execute()` in the for loop.

Alternatively, you can define `forEachComponet()` as a template:

```
template <class Task>
void forEachComponent(Universe& u, Task& task)
```

And now anything passed into this function must override `operator()`.